# integration ccavenue not working in test url

Tags: php, ccavenue

i have integrated ccavenue payment gateway using PHP. it works fine on secure url but it is not working on test url of ccavenue. so i can not find a way to test my integration.i have used the kit provided in the ccavenue  official website.but it causes problem. below is code the request page where all the user data is posted and than request send to the ccavenue. some one please help me how to solve this. thanks in advance.

```
<html>
<head>
<title> Custom Form Kit </title>
</head>
<body>
<center>

<?php 
    $merchant_data='';
    $working_key='*************';//Shared by CCAVENUES
    $access_code='******************';//Shared by CCAVENUES

    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value){
        $merchant_data.=$key.'='.urlencode($value).'&';
    }

    $encrypted_data=encrypt($merchant_data,$working_key); // Method for encrypting the data.

?>
<form method="post" name="redirect" action="https://test.ccavenue.com/transaction/transaction.do?command=initiateTransaction"> 
<?php
echo "<input type=hidden name=encRequest value=$encrypted_data>";
echo "<input type=hidden name=access_code value=$access_code>";
?>
</form>
</center>
<script language='javascript'>document.redirect.submit();</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you included some code so other users can provide direct feedback and suggestions.

Comment: For testing ccavenue you have to mail your merchant id and register site to ccavenue help team and they will activate your account for test environment.
mail account : service@ccavenue.com